# Is my laptop's battery dangerous?

Tags: laptop, battery

I've been using a battery in my laptop for 3 years and I've kept it in fairly good condition until now. My routine was to keep it plugged in most of the time but use it on battery once or twice a week to keep it 'exercised'.

Back in February the battery started charging only to 60%, then one day it stopped charging at all. Now I can have it plugged in for many hours and it wont budge past 2%, then that 2% charge is usually gone back to 0% by the following day. No matter what percentage it's at the computer will power off almost immediately if the charger is removed.

My question is, is this battery safe to keep in the laptop any more or should I replace it ASAP. I watched some (albeit manually induced) laptop battery fire videos on YouTube, in which one said not to use overcharged or overdischarged batteries, so preferably I would like to avoid that ever happening!

Thanks

Comment: Is the battery warm/hot to the touch?

Comment: @user1092719: Have you tried using the laptop without the battery?

Comment: @bobSmith1432 no it does not get any warmer than it got during normal functioning (not very at all).

Comment: @James I have not yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the battery anymore. You can safely unplug the battery and use the laptop that way though.

The problem is that if you charge a battery that is not accepting any input anymore, it will eventually burn out. There are protections in the battery, but it still remains to be electronics. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: Thanks. I will use the laptop without the battery later on. Sorry if this sounds stupid but since I prefer to use it on my lap, could I cover the gold contacts where the battery connected with paper/card/plastic and insulating tape so I don't get shocked or short circuit the laptop if I come into contact with them, or should I use it on a desk only? (Until I get a replacement battery). P.S. Apologies I can't up vote you as my reputation is too low at the moment.

Comment: Usually these contact points are hard to reach. Given that a battery is running on a low voltage, getting shocked is not really a risk you have to be affraid of. In the worst case, it might feel like an itch, but I doubt you'll feel it at all. Covering the battery contacts can be done if done properly, but try not to put anything on the gold plates that is sticky, or risk contaminating the contact points to where a battery, when placed just doesn't make any contact. Also, if this helped you, please accept my answer. :)